# NodeJS + Browserify: disallow duplicates of libraires

Tags: node.js, routes

When I'm using nodejs app in browser, I'm facing with problems of separating all functionality for some pages. As example: I have core bundle (with main functions), index bundle (with functionality just for index page), catalog, product and etc. But each of them have own jquery and another libraries and and, consequently, excess of weight and functionality.
Can i pack jquery and another libs just in core, but use them in another bundles? Or, maybe, i can use one bundle, but routing actions, how do I do this? What is better?

Answer (score 0):

I was found a temporary solution - `factor-bundle`, but maybe somebody knows more beautiful and native variant?